# How do you say "...and did not intend to actually stay."

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, traduction

I have "...et n'a pas l'intention de rester" (not sure if that is correct), but I really want to add in the word *actually* as I feel it would make the sentence a lot better (in this case). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think about how you would explain the meaning or purpose of *actually* in this sentence. If you can find a way to explain it, add it to your question. Then we may try to find a way to express that. *Actually* in itself doesn't mean much, it's just punctuation.

Comment: can you add some piece of context, that piece can have a lot of interpretation by itself.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I'd say it can be more than punctuation depending on the situation! I think the key is "contrary to appearances, expectations, or claims", and potentially adds a damning element here. But as Charly says, it's hard to know without more of the context.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly: *...et n'a pas vraiment l'intention de rester*

Answer (score 1):

I would like to say that this would possibly be: "...et il n'avait pas vraiment l'intention de rester"